# YUI Menu positioned behind div

Tags: button, menu, css-position

I have implemented a YUI split button with a menu.  The button with menu appears in a scrolling div between header and a footer divs.  When exposing the menu near the footer div, the menu appears behind the div.

I have tried positioning the footer div with a z-index of -1.  I have tried positioning the div (within the scrolling div) containing the button with menu using a z-index of 500.  The menu always appears behind the footer div.

I am not using a YUI layout.  Yet.  If I did would it help?>

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the **z-index** property, you also have to change the **position** property. The easiest thing to change it to is **position:relative**.

Try setting both of those properties.

I don't think YUI layout will assist you in this particular problem.

Answer (score -1):

I started using YUI layout and my issues no longer exist.